# Starting tvout via "am start"

Tags: adb

i have a widget to switch to tvout
I d like to start that widget manually via "am start" command.
This the manifest.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="8" android:versionName="2.2.1"   package="com.archos.tvoutwidget"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.tvout" />
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".TvOutWidget" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation" />
    <receiver android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:name="TvOutWidgetProvider">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="archos.intent.action.ARCHOS_UPDATE_TVOUT_WIDGET" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/tvout_widget_info" />
    </receiver>
 </application>
 </manifest>
```

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Just use:

```
am start -n com.archos.tvoutwidget/.TvOutWidget
```

You can start any app using:

```
am start -n package_name/activity_name
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After i entered your command i can see a screen with "LCD/TV display" written on top and nothing more. But the tablet can't switch to tv. All i want is start tv-out manually via command line. Is this possible ?

Comment: Get the logcat running using "adb logcat". Then manually open the tv-out widget and do whatever you want to do with it. Meanwhile, keep an eye on the logcat output and see what package/activity the widget starts. Then use that in your command line and open the widget.
Another thing you can do is to open the main menu of the app and try to navigate through it using key events to simulate un/dowm arrow navigation and go to the desired option and select it.

Comment: Thanks again. This is the only activity of the widget i can see from logcat: I/ActivityManager( 1286): Starting activity: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.archos.tvoutwidget/.TvOutWidgetProvider }. If i send this command:"am start -n com.archos.tvoutwidget/.TvOutWidgetProvider" i receive an error :"activity does not exist". Help me please